# how to add data from database to a page that has a floating action button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

here is my code that I already have:

```
Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(290, 545, 0, 0),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddProductPage()));
        },
      ),
      ),
```

and here is the part that I want to add to the pervious code:

```
ListView(
          children: items
              .map(
                (item) => Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(item.name),
                    subtitle: Text(
                        'Quantity: ${item.quantity}, Price: ${item.price}'),
                  ),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make a page that has both ListView and FloatingActionButton?

Comment: @Almis Yes that is what I want to do

Comment: Do you want the FloatingActionButton to overlap with ListView or to be under the ListView? In case of overlap, if the item is too long (width) then some part might be hidden under the FloatingActionButton but that might be okay with you.